# How to insert the dynamic multiple row values into a database

Tags: javascript, php

```js
 <script src="  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
<script>
     var i=0;
currentRow = null;
                            $("button#savebutton").click(function(){   
                                    
                                var cat = $("#cat-list").val();
                                var display = $("#displayname").val();
                                var subcat = $("#subcat-list").val(); 
                                var order = $("#privilage").val();        
                                i++;
                                var new_row = "<tr id='row"+i+"' class='info'><td class='cat'>" + cat + "</td><td class='display'>" + display + "</td><td class='type'>" + subcat +"</td><td>"+order +"</td><td><span class='editrow'><a class='fa fa-edit' href='javascript: void(0);'>Edit</a></span></td><td><span class='deleterow'><a class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' href=''>Delete</a></span></tr>";
                                if(currentRow){
                               
                      $("table tbody").find($(currentRow)).replaceWith(new_row);
                                  currentRow = null;
                                 }
                                 else{
                                 $("table tbody").append(new_row);
                                 }
                                 
                            });

                        $(document).on('click', 'span.deleterow', function () {
                                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                               return false;
                        });
                        $(document).on('click', 'span.editrow', function () {
     currentRow= $(this).parents('tr');                  
                   
     
                        });
      </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#secondbtn").click (function(){
                            var category = $("#cat-list").val();
                               var display = $("#displayname").val();
                               var subcat = $("#subcat-list").val(); 
                               var privilage = $("#privilage").val();
           alert(category);
         
         $.ajax({
 
        type:"POST",

        url:"query1.php",

        data:{display:display_name,category:category,subcat:pagename,privilage:privilage},

         success:function(data){
 
          alert("successfully updated");
         }         
         }); 
       
            });
         });
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">


<label>Select your Category:</label>
<input type="text" id="cat-list"/>
</br>


<label> Display Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="display_name" id="displayname" d />
</div>


<label> Select your Subcategory:</label>
<input type="text" id="subcat-list" >

<label>Set Order</label>
<select name="privilage" id="privilage" required>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>



</form>



  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class = "panel1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savebtn" style="padding: 6px 12px;margin-left: 40%;" id="savebutton" onclick="getFirstClicked()" ><i class="icon-check-sign" aria-hidden="false"></i>Add</button>
    
   </div>
  </div>

  </form>
  <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="chargestableForm">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table id="pTable" class="table table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px; height:10px;" >
                  <thead style="background-color:#CCE5FF">
                       <tr>
           
                          <th>Category</th>
                          <th>DisplayName</th>
                          <th>Subcategory</th> 
                          <th>Order</th>         
                          <th colspan=2>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
       <tbody>     
                         </tbody>
            </table>
    <div class = "panel2">
     <button type="submit" name="import" id="secondbtn"  > Import Database</button>
              </div>
     </div>
           </form>
```

Context:In this code there is an html form,when adding the details in the form and clicks the add button there is a table row is created which is editable and delete. Then we can add the number of rows and that rows are added upto the table.I want to enter these table row values to a database when clicking the import button.

Comment: your snippet is broken.

Comment: The code indentation in the question, that's ... awful.

Comment: click full page